# How to grab Amazon ASIN number using regex in Javascript?

Tags: regex

```
www.amazon.in/gp/slredirect/picassoRedirect.html/ref=pa_sp_atf_next_aps_sr_pg2_1?ie=UTF8&adId=A00689312QGP01ZB3KM3N&url=%2FLifebuoy-Alcohol-Based-Protection-Sanitizer%2Fdp%2FB0866JTZXN%2Fref%3Dsr_1_49_sspa%3Fdchild%3D1%26keywords%3DHand%2Bsanitizer%26qid%3D1622721840%26smid%3DAT95IG9ONZD7S%26sr%3D8-49-spons%26psc%3D1&qualifier=1622721840&id=1588289180417395&widgetName=sp_atf_next
```

ASIN = B0866JTZXN

How do i get the asin number?

Comment: please make an attempt yourself before asking for others to do the work

Comment: Try this `%2F([A-Z0-9]+)%2F`

Comment: @DivyanshuSah You need to get the value from group 1.

Comment: @AdmirMisini You need `%2F([A-Z0-9]+)%2Fref` to narrow it down better since there are more than two `%2F`

Comment: @DivyanshuSah https://stackoverflow.com/questions/432493/how-do-you-access-the-matched-groups-in-a-javascript-regular-expression

Answer (score 2):

What you have is structured data in the form of a URL. You can use plain JavaScript without regex to parse and traverse it:

1. Parse as search parameters.
2. Get the parameter `url`.
3. Split the result into parts.
4. Get the part after `/dp/`.

```js
function extractASIN(url) {
  const searchParams = new URLSearchParams(url);
  const queryURL = searchParams.get("url");
  const parts = queryURL.split("/");
  const precedingIndex = parts.indexOf("dp");

  return parts[precedingIndex+1];
}

test("www.amazon.in/gp/slredirect/picassoRedirect.html/ref=pa_sp_atf_next_aps_sr_pg2_1?ie=UTF8&adId=A00689312QGP01ZB3KM3N&url=%2FLifebuoy-Alcohol-Based-Protection-Sanitizer%2Fdp%2FB0866JTZXN%2Fref%3Dsr_1_49_sspa%3Fdchild%3D1%26keywords%3DHand%2Bsanitizer%26qid%3D1622721840%26smid%3DAT95IG9ONZD7S%26sr%3D8-49-spons%26psc%3D1&qualifier=1622721840&id=1588289180417395&widgetName=sp_atf_next");

test("www.amazon.in/gp/slredirect/picassoRedirect.html/ref=pa_sp_atf_aps_sr_pg1_1?ie=UTF8&adId=A027625218II94KXW8EWJ&url=%2FDettol-Sanitizer-Regular-200-Pack%2Fdp%2FB076ZH5ZJL%2Fref%3Dsr_1_2_sspa%3Fdchild%3D1%26keywords%3DHand%2Bsanitizer%26qid%3D1622720663%26sr%3D8-2-spons%26psc%3D1&qualifier=1622720663&id=6679001242725581&widgetName=sp_atf");

function test(str) {
  const result = extractASIN(str);
  console.log(`ASIN = ${result}`);
}
```

Alternatively, you can use basic string manipulation

1. Get where `dp%2F` is.
2. Where the next `%2F` is.
3. Extract the string between the two.

```js
function extractASIN(url) {
  const startToken = "dp%2F";
  const endToken = "%2F";
  
  const start = url.indexOf(startToken) + startToken.length;
  const end = url.indexOf(endToken, start);
  
  return url.slice(start, end);
}

test("www.amazon.in/gp/slredirect/picassoRedirect.html/ref=pa_sp_atf_next_aps_sr_pg2_1?ie=UTF8&adId=A00689312QGP01ZB3KM3N&url=%2FLifebuoy-Alcohol-Based-Protection-Sanitizer%2Fdp%2FB0866JTZXN%2Fref%3Dsr_1_49_sspa%3Fdchild%3D1%26keywords%3DHand%2Bsanitizer%26qid%3D1622721840%26smid%3DAT95IG9ONZD7S%26sr%3D8-49-spons%26psc%3D1&qualifier=1622721840&id=1588289180417395&widgetName=sp_atf_next");

test("www.amazon.in/gp/slredirect/picassoRedirect.html/ref=pa_sp_atf_aps_sr_pg1_1?ie=UTF8&adId=A027625218II94KXW8EWJ&url=%2FDettol-Sanitizer-Regular-200-Pack%2Fdp%2FB076ZH5ZJL%2Fref%3Dsr_1_2_sspa%3Fdchild%3D1%26keywords%3DHand%2Bsanitizer%26qid%3D1622720663%26sr%3D8-2-spons%26psc%3D1&qualifier=1622720663&id=6679001242725581&widgetName=sp_atf");

function test(str) {
  const result = extractASIN(str);
  console.log(`ASIN = ${result}`);
}
```

If you really want a regex, you can use `/dp%2F(\w*)%2F/` to capture the value between `dp%2F` and `%2F` then return it:

```js
function extractASIN(url) {
  return url.match(/dp%2F(\w*)%2F/)[1];
}

test("www.amazon.in/gp/slredirect/picassoRedirect.html/ref=pa_sp_atf_next_aps_sr_pg2_1?ie=UTF8&adId=A00689312QGP01ZB3KM3N&url=%2FLifebuoy-Alcohol-Based-Protection-Sanitizer%2Fdp%2FB0866JTZXN%2Fref%3Dsr_1_49_sspa%3Fdchild%3D1%26keywords%3DHand%2Bsanitizer%26qid%3D1622721840%26smid%3DAT95IG9ONZD7S%26sr%3D8-49-spons%26psc%3D1&qualifier=1622721840&id=1588289180417395&widgetName=sp_atf_next");

test("www.amazon.in/gp/slredirect/picassoRedirect.html/ref=pa_sp_atf_aps_sr_pg1_1?ie=UTF8&adId=A027625218II94KXW8EWJ&url=%2FDettol-Sanitizer-Regular-200-Pack%2Fdp%2FB076ZH5ZJL%2Fref%3Dsr_1_2_sspa%3Fdchild%3D1%26keywords%3DHand%2Bsanitizer%26qid%3D1622720663%26sr%3D8-2-spons%26psc%3D1&qualifier=1622720663&id=6679001242725581&widgetName=sp_atf");

function test(str) {
  const result = extractASIN(str);
  console.log(`ASIN = ${result}`);
}
```